# How TCP flow's rate change when congestion occur

Tags: networking, tcp, iperf, congestion-control

Thank you for clicking my question.

I'm doing a small experiment for understanding the behavior of TCP flows at congestion.

At this experiment, I found the tcp flow's rate is much bigger than I think, when congestion occur.

I think its rate should become halve at most, due to its congestion control.

But it didn't at my experiment.

Could you give me a little hint? Below is my experiment.

Thank you for click again

---

---

I made a small network by using `Mininet` consisting two hosts and a switch.

**H1 - S1 - H2** , with all of link BW 80Mbps

Then, I generated traffic form H2 to H1 by using `iperf3` like below

```
#H1
iperf3 -s -p 1212 -f m -i 1

#H2
iperf3 -c 10.0.0.1 -p 1212 -t 10000 -f m -b 70M
```

It means H2 send TCP packets to H1, at 70Mbit/s

(iperf3 controls its TCP rate at appication layer.)

Then we can see the report at H1 (server siide)

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 1212
-----------------------------------------------------------
Accepted connection from 10.0.0.2, port 51786
[ 17] local 10.0.0.1 port 1212 connected to 10.0.0.2 port 51788
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[ 17]   0.00-1.00   sec  7.49 MBytes  62.8 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   1.00-2.00   sec  8.14 MBytes  68.3 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   2.00-3.00   sec  8.54 MBytes  71.7 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   3.00-4.00   sec  8.60 MBytes  72.2 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   4.00-5.00   sec  7.98 MBytes  66.9 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   5.00-6.00   sec  8.80 MBytes  73.9 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   6.00-7.00   sec  8.21 MBytes  68.9 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   7.00-8.00   sec  7.77 MBytes  65.1 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   8.00-9.00   sec  8.30 MBytes  69.7 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   9.00-10.00  sec  8.45 MBytes  70.9 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]  10.00-11.00  sec  8.32 MBytes  69.7 Mbits/sec
```

At this time, I throttle the S1 port (s1-eth1, egress from H2 to H1) by using `linux tc`

```
sudo tc qdisc del dev s1-eth1 root
sudo tc qdisc add dev s1-eth1 root tbf rate 40mbit latency 10ms burst 1mbit
```

Then the result is below

```
[ 17]   0.00-1.00   sec  7.76 MBytes  65.0 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   1.00-2.00   sec  8.09 MBytes  67.9 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   2.00-3.00   sec  8.53 MBytes  71.5 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   3.00-4.00   sec  8.47 MBytes  71.0 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   4.00-5.00   sec  8.08 MBytes  67.8 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   5.00-6.00   sec  8.09 MBytes  67.9 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   6.00-7.00   sec  8.74 MBytes  73.3 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   7.00-8.00   sec  7.81 MBytes  65.6 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   8.00-9.00   sec  8.35 MBytes  70.0 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]   9.00-10.00  sec  4.56 MBytes  38.3 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]  10.00-11.00  sec  4.56 MBytes  38.2 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]  11.00-12.00  sec  4.56 MBytes  38.2 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]  12.00-13.00  sec  4.56 MBytes  38.2 Mbits/sec                  
[ 17]  13.00-14.00  sec  4.56 MBytes  38.2 Mbits/sec
```

As you see, its rate is about 40Mbps.

I think when congestion occur, TCP state should become `slow start` and then Its rate should become much smaller. But it didn't.

I check the `iperf3` source code but It just make TCP traffic to the amount from application layer. Therefore it don't have an effect to the behavior of TCP algorithm.

Why did it happen? I don't know...

Could you give me a little hint? I appreciate you!

Comment: The most efficient way to see what´s happening at better resolution (1 sec is a loong time for a network) I´d recommend capturing traffic with Wireshark or similar.

Comment: @C.Gonzalez Thank you so much! I monitor traffic right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I have to set parameters properly before the experiment.

**1) When setting link bandwidth, we can set the burst size(,or mtu size) at `TC` setting.**

it looks have an effect on the fluctuation of the `iperf` TCP flow.

when the burst size is small, its rate fluctuated or is low, than I expected.

**2) Also, we can set the MTU size(Jumbo frame size) at switch.**

Because I use OVS(`OpenVSwitch`), I set the parameter as [the site](http://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/topics/dpdk/jumbo-frames/).

**3) And, we can set the MTU size at interface card by using `ethtool`.**
You can see [this site](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-can-i-setup-the-mtu-for-my-network-interface/).

---

After setting above parameters properly, it is desirable to observe the TCP rate.

The reason why the TCP rate isn't smaller despite of congestion seems **small RTT value**.

As in [the slide](https://www.slideshare.net/deawooKim/cubic-kdw), TCP transmitte its packet at every RTT.

In my experiment, RTT is much smaller value because there is only a edge between two host.

Therefore, in a second scale, it looks the host do not decrease it rate but it do in reality.